# Magento PDF invoices

Tags: magento-1.7, theme

I know about the default.php, and the abstract.php

I saw in one tutorial that there are phtml file mentioned for Magento PDF invoices.

Does someone knows where are from informations in Magento pdf invoices pulled from? Are there any phtml files that can be edited and to affect content of Magento PDF invoices?

Also, I see that the recommendation is always to copy magento files in your own theme? How can I do that? In what folder?

Thanks!

Josip

Answer (score 2):

Replicate `app/code/core/*` files to the same path at `app/code/local/*`

Replicate `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/*` files to the same path at `app/design/frontend/theme_package/default/layout/*`

Replicate `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/*` files to the same path at `app/design/frontend/theme_package/default/template/*`

Following the above ensures you are extending Magento so that any future upgrades to the Magento platform will not overwrite what changes you have made. Only the files that you wish to modify need to be replicated at the local/theme paths.

You can edit how the PDF's are constructed by extending the files at  `app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf` - without knowing exactly what you wish to do within the PDF's, it's hard to elaborate but no, there isn't any template files to edit the PDF's directly because they are constructed using the Zend_Pdf component of the Zend framework of which you can learn more about [here](http://devzone.zend.com/1064/zend_pdf-tutorial).

Comment: I just copied Mage and Zend folders to app/code/local and I'm not sure why but I received critic about his from expirienced Magento developer. Are you sure this is the proper way of seperating things?

Comment: You only copy the particular files you wish to extend/modify in the replicated paths (within local) rather than the entire folders...